# How to make Manipulate run automatically after evaluation?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, scheduling

How to make `Manipulate` run/play automatically after evaluation, i.e. without having to hit the *play* button (but still being able to use the *pause/play* button)?

```
Manipulate[ Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {k, 0, 50, 1, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

(No, I don't want to use `Animate`.)

Comment: `{k, 0, 50, 1, ControlType -> Animator, Appearance -> "Open"}` - help me find a duplicate.

Comment: @Kuba I haven't found an explicit duplicat, hence decided to post this question. `ControlType -> Animator` works, but... it somehow overrides `Appearance -> "Open"` - i.e. it's closed, not open (v10.4 and v11.1, Linux).

Comment: It is open for me though Animator does not have input field by default. What about `{k, 0, 50, 1, ControlType -> Animator, Appearance -> "Open", 
 AppearanceElements -> All}`?

Comment: @Kuba Ok, I wasn't clear - the buttons are indeed open, but with the input field lacking, I would need to somehow tweak the plot further to have the current `k` value visible. I hoped there might be something like `Autoplay -> True`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken only `Animator` based controllers have `AnimationRunning` option. We can use it, but `Animator` does not have InputField appearance element. We can add it separately, but it will be tricky to hide it. So let's assume you don't have to:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
, {k, 0, 50, 1, ControlType -> Animator}
, {{k, 0, ""}, 0, 50, 1, ControlType -> InputField}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And adding `FieldSize -> 5` after the `InputField` makes it look like the default.